# C++ next_permutation function

Tags: c++

Im trying to write a program that will ask you to enter a four letter word. Then you're program will display all the possible four letter combinations based on the given word. Example, you entered the word TEST. Then you're program will display the following :
TSTE TTES etc.
based on my research and a little bit of googling i created this:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
std::string s = "";
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
do {
    std::cout << "Please Enter any Letter" << '\n';
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << " The Permutation is " << s <<'\n' << endl;
} while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end
}
```

so when i try to enter a four letter word its just display the letter and permutation doesnt happen. What am i doing wrong here?
PS Im still a beginner and a student learning C++ so please explain it clearly TY :)

Comment: Umm ... you're asking the user to enter a word in each iteration of the loop. You should move the `cout` and `cin` ahead of the loop and ask the user for a 4 letter word, not a single letter at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::cin >> s;` takes input from the user. Given what you are trying to do, it makes no sense to do that every time in the loop. Move it outside the loop and run through the permutations in the loop.

```
std::string s = "";
std::cout << "Please Enter any word" << '\n';
std::cin >> s;
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
do {
    std::cout << " The Permutation is " << s <<'\n' << endl;
} while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end);
```